# CefSharp detect if audio is being played

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Is it possible to detect if audio is being played in CefSharp?

For example, I have a browser game that plays a `.wav` sound every time you pick up a coin, and I need to detect that.

Fortunately, the game has no other sound except for collecting coins, so it is enough to just broadly detect if any audio is playing or initiated.

I tried searching to see if there's any CefSharp audio handlers, but I couldn't find any information, so anything will be helpful - thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/76e5a8d5c0541dfe5235c6d43d2b41187ce6ef0f/CefSharp.Example/Handlers/AudioHandler.cs#L23

Comment: @amaitland Thanks. Just wondering, is it possible to get information such as audio file that's playing, audio length, etc?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The handler only provides raw data. You can probably execute some javascript to get details out of the browser.